# How to Pass paramenter to javascript in webview

Tags: iphone, webview

I have to pass argument to javascript function from Webview, but it is calling properly.

Thanks
Vadivelu

Answer (score 0):

Well ! I am just going to give an example. I know its too late ( almost a year :P )

```
 [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollTo(0,%i);",kPageSize*(self.currentPage-1)]];
```

You can notice that, I have passed a parameter to javascript from objective-c.

This will cause webView to scroll some-where within a webView.

Hope it helps.

Note : Please do not forget to accept answer if it is helpful to you. ( as I noticed most of your questions are not accepted. )